# TypeError: must be str, not list - list of words

Tags: python

For a current project, I am planning to count the occurrence of a number of specific words within a data set.

For the code line `count = word.count(wordlist)`, I am however receiving the following error `TypeError: must be str, not list`. Is there any smart way to have Python accept a word list, so not only check for one specific but for several words?

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
# Word frequency analysis
def get_top_n_bigram(corpus, n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english').fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]


# Analysis loops running through different string sections
for i in ['Text_Pro','Text_Con','Text_Main']:
    common_words = get_top_n_bigram(df[i], 500)
    for word, freq in common_words:
        print(word, freq)


# Analysis loops checking if specific words are found
    for word in common_words:
        wordlist = ['good', 'management', 'bad']
        count = word.count(wordlist)
        print(count)
```

Comment: Count the  occurences of each word then sum them

Comment: the uses are `str.count(otherstr)` to count substring or `list.count(item)` to count the number of occurence, yoru version doesn't exist

Comment: There's no way that I know of to have `count` look for multiple elements at once. You'd need multiple calls to `count`, or write your own function that accepts a list and checks for occurrences .

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. It seems like I would need a separate `count` command for each of the words and sum things up then

Comment: Ya. That would be incredibly inefficient though, as it would require a full iteration of the string for each word to check for. If efficiency is at all important, I'd just write up a quick loop that checks for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
count = 0
for word in common_words:
    wordlist = ['good', 'management', 'bad']
    count += sum([word.count(i) for i in wordlist])

print(count)
```

As a dictionary, per request from the comment section to this answer:

```
count = {}
for word in common_words:
    wordlist = ["good", "management", "bad"]
    count[word] = sum([word.count(i) for i in wordlist])

print(count)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the good input - that helped to get rid of the TypeError. It however yields empty results for the multi-word search, while I had results for the "single word" search...

Comment: Can you give an example of your multi-word search?

Comment: Ok I ran it again and get useful output now. Results are in the format `0,1,0,0,0,0,1`, so Python is comparing every single word token to the pre-defined words and checking if there is a match or not...

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: As a very quick question - is there any chance to sum up the number of matches per specific word instead of the `0,1,0,0,0,0,1` format?

Comment: You mean to map each word to it's count, as in a dictionary with the word as key and its count as value ?

Comment: Yup that's what I mean, in case there is a way to make this happen

Comment: See the updated answer for a dictionary solution as well.

Comment: Many thanks for your initiative here. This one is yielding dictionary-like blocks `('compensations work', 1): 0, ('environment best', 1): 0, ('best good', 1): 0, ('good management', 1): 0,` - let me see if I can figure out a way to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the more efficient, but more verbose way of checking against a set in an old-fashioned loop:

```
from typing import Iterable

def count_many(string: str, words: Iterable[str]) -> int:
    search_set = set(words)  # To ease lookups
    split = string.split()  # Cut into words

    count = 0
    for word in split:
        if word in search_set:
            count += 1

    return count

>>> count_many("hello world hello no world hello", ["hello", "world"])
5
```

Put the words to lookup in a set for faster lookups, split the source text into words, then just loop and count.

This should do, regardless of the length of `words`, two iterations of the source text.

Comment: Thanks for this. The code runs through without errors but I do not see any output in my terminal. Let me check how this can be solved.

Comment: @M.S. This function returns the data; it doesn't print. If you want it to print in a non-REPL environment, you'd need to explicitly call `print` on the return: `print(count_many("hello world hello no world hello", ["hello", "world"]))`. My example at the bottom printed because I ran it in a REPL.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that and had already amended it to `print` beforehand. Nonetheless not seeing any output in the terminal...

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to examine every word regardless, we may as well build the entire histogram of word frequency, and then extract the word counts that we're interested in:

```
from collections import Counter

def words_matching(sentence, candidates):
    histogram = Counter(sentence.split())
    return sum(histogram[word] for word in candidates)
```